# ZF2 navigation sitemap error

Tags: navigation, zend-framework2, sitemap

I can draw navigation menu and breadcrumbs without problem , but when I want to use sitemap the following error occures :

```
Zend\Uri\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: no class registered for scheme "javascript"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$this->navigation('CONTAINER_NAME')
  ->sitemap()
  ->setUseSitemapValidators(false)     //Default is true
  ->setFormatOutput(true);

echo $this->navigation()->sitemap();
```